# HTML & Javascript, how can I make a button appear in a function?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm still new to HTML and JS, but I want to make a function that makes a button appear on the webpage... I've tried a couple of things like this:

HTML:

```
<span id="buttonAppear"></span>
```

JS:

```
function buttonFunction(){
     document.getElementById("buttonAppear").innerHTML = "<button onclick="secondFunction()">Some text here</button>";
}
```

But of course, that didn't work. I'd love to hear a good way to make this happen.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why didnt it work? Did you get an error at all, have you tried debugging it? Its most likely due to the quotes. Try using `'` instead of `"` around the button html

Comment: `\"` may be useful. Basic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should appear.
You have to slash your innerHtml or use single quotes so you do not mess when mixing them:

```
function buttonFunction(){
     document.getElementById("buttonAppear").innerHTML = '<button onclick="secondFunction()">Some text here</button>';
}
```

Comment: Ahh, yes this works. Simple beginners mistake... Feel stupid now, haha.. Thanks for the answer! Accepting it in a couple of mins.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of quotes, as Andrea has pointed it out in his reply. Your version would only work if you escaped the inner double quotes, like this:

```js
function buttonFunction(){
     document.getElementById("buttonAppear").innerHTML = "<button onclick=\"secondFunction()\">Some text here</button>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first escape what you're attaching to the DOM. You also presumably want to run this when the page is loaded or some other event has happened.

Using jQuerys .ready() will load whatever you have when the page is loaded fully. Then pass in your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById("buttonAppear").innerHTML = '<button
    onclick=\'secondFunction()\'>Some text here</button>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is always going to be the same you can just show and hide it dynamically...

```
/*In your CSS*/
 .hidden {
    display: none;
}
.show {
   display: inline;
}
<!-- In your HTML -->
<button id="button" class="hidden">test</button>

// In your js
function toggleButton() {
    document.getElementById("button").className = 'show'; 
}
```